# Laravel error on logout

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have a custom `AppUserProvider` to fetch my users from a cache setup like so:

```
class AppUserProvider extends \Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider {

    public function retrieveById($identifier)
    {
        return \App\Models\User::getById($identifier);
    }
}
```

I then set a custom property on it in the `getById` method after retrieving the object with Eloquent and return it.

```
$user->test = 'test';
```

Everything works fine, but when I hit logout I get an error.

```
update `users` set `test` = ?, `remember_token` = ?, `updated_at` = ? where `id` = ?')
```

Not sure why it's trying to update the `test` parameter.

Comment: What is this `test` attribute for? When Laravel runs an update on a model it takes all (changed) attributes and puts them in the query.

Comment: I'm actually storing permissions from key/value to parameters for easy access, like `Auth::user()->permissions->save_file`. Maybe there is a better way to process this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everytime when you set a property on an Eloquent model that doesn't actually exist (is not defined in the class) `__set()` is called and Laravel stores the value as a model attribute. Then when running an update, Laravel notices that you added a new attribute and adds it to the update query.

You prevent that by simply defining the property in your model:

```
public $test;
```

Or if you want to use said property like an object, you should initialize it as one:

```
public $permissions;

public function __construct(array $attributes = array()){
    $this->permissions = new stdClass;
    parent::__construct($attributes);
}
```